# Swift collection view button affecting other cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, core-animation

I have a custom collection view with a mark favorite button at the top which when pressed should show a Instagram like heart animation at the center. What I have done so far causes the heart animation to appear in some other random cells of course that is due to this code of reusing identifier.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "shopCell", for: indexPath) as! ShopCell
```

but how should I resolve this issue? I have read multiple posts about it and implemented the solution but none of them worked for me. For example setting index path to cell and after that using delegation on button click

```
cell.indexPath = indexPath
```

and in my shop cell I have

```
@IBAction func favHeartBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.favoriteButton(sender: self)
}
```

In my shopView I have this

```
func favoriteButton(sender: ShopCollectionViewCell) {  
    sender.centerHeart.isHidden = false
    sender.centerHeart.zoomIn()
}
```

Still animation starts in other cells. Even if I put a check for indexPath

Comment: Didn't understand. You want to show the heart animation in centre of the view right? If i am correct then why to depend on collectionviewcell. Use the frame of your superview.

Comment: How about simply animate inside your cell? Doesn't seem it has to be triggered from the controller.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I mean at the center of my cell when it's tapped.

Comment: @sCha  tried from doing it from cell still doesn't work and animates other cells as I am using reuse identifier.

Comment: When you set up the cell in cell(forItem: at:) are you cleaning it down by hiding the heart icon again? Whenever I create a collection view whose cells have contingent sub views I always do this after queuing up a cell.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Please explain it more clearly if possible.

Comment: @PGDev. There are two hearts in my collection view one is the topRightHeart and other one is centerHeart. The centerHeart is invisible by default. I want that whenever I click topRightHeart the centerHeart becomes visible zoomsIn and fade away. I already have the perfect animation code. But the issues is whenever I click on the topRightHeart some other cells centerHeart becomes visible. I need to show centerHeart animation on the exact same cell of which topRightHeart is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the show/hide of the center heart in your custom `UICollectionViewCell`, i.e.

```
class CustomCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var centerHeart: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.centerHeart.alpha = 0.0
    }

    @IBAction func onTapHeartButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
            self.centerHeart.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (completed) in
            if completed
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
                    self.centerHeart.alpha = 0.0
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add whatever animation you need according to your requirement.

**Sample Project:** https://github.com/pgpt10/CollectionViewSample

Comment: Already tried it doesn't work. Still it animates other cells due to the reuse identifier I think. If you can please make a dummy project add a button and a label in collection view then try that whenever the button is pressed only the label in that cell is hidden. If you are able to achieve this it would do the trick.

Comment: I have added the sample project link in the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks @PGDev your code is working fine I don't know what's the issue in my code although I am doing a similar thing. I will try for it's resolution and let mark the answer.

Comment: Sure. Happy coding.:)

Comment: I don't know what special thing you did and I didn't. Although your and my logic is exactly the same but still the heart of other cells start to animate don't know why.

Comment: Can you show your complete code so I can check and figure out.

Comment: It's working in your project but I don't know why it isn't working for me.

Comment: I asked you to show more of your code so I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

In your class create array with indexes:

```
var favoriteList = [Int]()
```

In cell setup code you set button’s tag to the indexPath.row

```
[skip cell setup code]
cell.centerHeart.tag = indexPath.row
```

Your favoriteButton will look like:

```
func favoriteButton(sender: ShopCollectionViewCell) {
    ///update model
    favoriteList.append(sender.tag)
    ///refresh UI
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In this delegate you check IndexPath. And if you found this indexPath in list, you show button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.shouldAnimateCell(indexPath) {
        cell.showHearthAnimation(indexPath)
    } else {
        cell.hideHearthAnimation()
    }   
}


func showHearthAnimation(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(indexPath)

    cell.displayCenterHearth()
}

func hideHearthAnimation(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(indexPath)

    cell.hideCenterHearth()
}

func shouldAnimateCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    return self.favoriteList.contains(indexPath.row)
}
```

And for cell you implement:

```
func displayCenterHearth() {
    self.centerHeart.isHidden = false
    self.centerHeart.zoomIn()
}
func hideCenterHearth() {
    self.centerHeart.isHidden = true
}
```

This solution should work for you. Sorry for possible mistakes, I have used  TextEditor to write this code.

---

What is major issue of the original solution. We are using MVC. And it means that we have model and view. When you press button, you update your UI (view) but you don't do anything with your data model. Right scenarios is: update model and reload or refresh view.

I believe you already have data model and it looks like:

```
var model: [Record]

struct Record {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
}
```

To make it works with your data model, set isFavorite property to true in delegate method and rewrite shouldAnimateCell.

```
func favoriteButton(sender: ShopCollectionViewCell) {
    ///update model
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender)

    self.model[indexPath.row].isFavorite = true

    ///refresh UI
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func shouldAnimateCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    return self.model[indexPath.row].isFavorite
}
```

Comment: You are right about the data model but I am using isFavorite for marking another icon and it's working perfectly. The issue is I want to show the animation as soon as the item is marked favorite not for the already favorite items.

Comment: Follow the same idea.

1. update model. Use isAnimating property for example. 
2. reload cell
3. from tableView delegate methods - configure and update UI

Answer (score 0):

Although PGDev answer was perfect and I accepted it as the right answer. The issue which was causing the PGDev code to not work in my custom class was that I was using delegation for the button.

```
cell.delegate = self
```

I removed this line and added the code for the animation which PGDev has provided in the cell IBOutlet for the button and this did the trick.